# Postgresql index for SELECT MAX(x) FROM table WHERE y=y1 AND z=z1

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table(x, y, z) with millions tow, and query like

`SELECT MAX(x) FROM table WHERE y=y1 AND z=z1`

What is the best index to optimize this query? I tried everything, but it's always very slow.

Comment: Post the output of `explain analyze SELECT MAX(x) FROM table WHERE y=y1 AND z=z1` and `\d table`

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: This is a good candidate for a trigger-maintained materialized view, unless you have lots of concurrent inserts of `x` for any given `(y,z)` pair.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably it must be

```
(y, z, x)
```

or

```
(z, y, z)
```

depending on what other queries you perform.

A note: it will only be useful if the cardinality of the given `(x, y, z)` tuple is high.